# Mysql join 4 tables and get sum

Tags: php, mysql, join

i need to join 4 tables. I have users table and need to connect with customers and than both connect to profiles for that i using relations table and later get the sum.

My result would be as good

```
2 Thomas White   2.56 180.00 461.89 0.00 0.00 0.00 antras komentaras
3 Doina Slaivici 5.87 161.17 946.88 0.00 0.00      vienas komentaras
```

but problem is with profiles comments im getting only from single profile comment, not from all, because some users have few profiles.

My join:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  users.id AS uid,
  users.sum_per_hour AS usum_per_hour,
  SUM(
    customers.sum / 4.33 / customers.days_per_week * profiles.days
  ) AS total_sum 
FROM
  users,
  relations,
  customers,
  profiles 
WHERE users.id = relations.uid 
  AND customers.id = relations.cid 
  AND profiles.uid = relations.uid 
  AND profiles.cid = relations.cid 
GROUP BY users.id
```

[image]

Comment: ***Please*** stop using implicit join syntax.

Comment: You're doing an n-way join, where each of the joined tables has some different number of records. You'll be getting very wonky results due to the record count mismatches.

Comment: you should try changing it to left joins for the tables.

Comment: The structure and content of table Relations is duplicated in table Profiles.  Relations appears to be unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnRuddell i need info from three tables, but left join returns only from single table?

Comment: @SkySonny I created [THIS POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056?noredirect=1#comment92604_271056) for users to understand how to better ask a question. if you can edit your question and include the points made it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try changing your FROM to this

```
SELECT 
    *,
    u.id AS uid,
    u.sum_per_hour AS usum_per_hour,
    SUM(c.sum / 4.33 / c.days_per_week * p.days) AS total_sum 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN relations r 
  ON u.id = r.uid
LEFT JOIN customers c 
  ON c.id = r.cid 
LEFT JOIN profiles p 
  ON p.uid = r.uid 
  AND p.cid = r.cid -- # -- this may need to be OR instead of AND
GROUP BY u.id
```

I honestly don't know if this will solve your issue... you have to ask a better question.. meaning show your result you are currently getting.. post the data (not images) or even better post a sqlfiddle so we can use it ourselves.. and then show your expected result. but this is a guess from what I can see

Comment: still same problem i dont get all comments from profile table, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b26992/2